# Constraining Curve Angles on Existing Paths

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When drawing paths, I can easily constrain the next point to 45° increments by holding Shift.  How do I hold these same angles when modifying existing paths?  I want to ensure lines that appear level are actually level, and cannot think of a way to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a job for guides. Open View > Rulers and click the top or left ruler and drag a guide to the position you want other lines level with. You can also manually position guides by % or px, lock them with " Ctrl Alt + " to avoid repositioning and show / hide them with " Ctrl [ "

Also worth noting: If you set View > Snap to > Guides, anything you drag near the guide will adhere or "snap" to it instantly, making it more precise and easier to abide by.

[image: Photoshop Guides]

Comment: Thanks again.  I suppose the functionality I am looking for in Photoshop does not exist, but your solution is the next best thing.  I was using the measure tool, but guides looks easier.  Thanks Brian.

Comment: Happy to have helped, I added a side note that I also thought may come in handy.